# Drawing a pyramid of stars

Tags: java, loops

I need to write a program that will print the following output

```
            * 
          * * *
         * * * *
```

but my code till now is printing instead this

```
                      * 
                     * * 
                    * * *
```

My code is:

```
public class Pyramid2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4 - i; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks little weird, but just do not run the loop for value of i = 1, ideally pyramid is always 1, 2 , 3... so on structure type...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
            if (i != 1) {
                for (int j = 0 ; j < 4 - i ; j++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                for (int k = 0 ; k <= i ; k++) {
                    System.out.print("* ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
    * 
  * * * 
 * * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that there might be an error in the assignment, and that three separate print statements would be a perfectly good way of executing it. 
   Seems you could also slip in an if statement to exclude the line with two stars from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Lower Piramid Part, I was doing for some other answer,But that one is closed now. So check below once hope it may help

```
//      *  *  *  *  *  *  *
//         *  *  *  *  *
//            *  *  * 
//               *
//            *  *  *
//         *  *  *  *  *
//      *  *  *  *  *  *  *


    // Insert input for Total Use only odd Number
        int total = 11, t = 0;
        // Upper Piramid
        for (int i = 0; i < total / 2; i++) {
            t = 0;
            for (int k = i; k > 0; k--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                t++;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < total - (t * 2); j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < t; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        total = total - (total / 2);
        // Lower Piramid
        for (int i = total; i > 0; i--) {
            t = 0;
            for (int j = i; j > 1; j--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                t++;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < total - t; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (int j = 1; j < total - t; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            for (int j = i; j > 1; j--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```